# js обьект и аргумент функции

Tags: javascript, функции, объекты

у меня встал вопрос.Как работает код ниже,а именно момент с return rub* rate[currency]
Я правильно понимаю ,что в аргумент функции мы передаем обьект rate?Но почему тогда аргумент  в квадратных скобках?Где про это можно прочитать?(я видимо плохо искал ничего не нашел похожего).

```
const rate = {
    usd: 0.026 ,
    eur: 0.024,
}

function convert(rub,currency){
    if(!rate[currency]) {
        return null
    }
    return rub * rate[currency]
}
```

Comment: Какой умилительный пример десятилетней давности 

Answer (score 1):

> Я правильно понимаю ,что в аргумент функции мы передаем обьект rate

**Нет**. Тут два параметра, например `999` и `usd`  или `123` и `eur`

> почему тогда аргумент в квадратных скобках?

К свойствам объекта можно обращаться не только через точку (типа `rate.usd`), но и через квадратные скобки (типа `rate['usd']`). Называется [скобочная нотация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics#%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C_bracket_notation). В итоге, если `currency` будет `'usd'`, то будет в итоге `rate['usd']` и, соответственно, значение по этому ключу 0,026